# Transpose R data frame with text data

Tags: r

I have been getting more familiar with R and learning about long and wide data frames. I am getting decent at using dcast (and ddply), but as far as I can tell, they rely on my data being numerical. In the following example, I have:

```
data.frame(color=c("red","orange","blue","white"),safe=c("N","N","Y","Y"))
```

Basically, the old assumption that insurance companies penalized "risky colors" of cars as being less safe. I'd like a command to turn this into a wide table. Is there a flavor or syntax of dcast I'm missing that would turn the above table into

```
red | orange | blue | white
 N  |   N    |  Y   |   Y
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe dis `reshape2::dcast(df, . ~ color, value.var = "safe")[-1]`?

Comment: Or `rownames(df) <- df$color; df$color <- NULL; t(df)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the `transpose` function?

```
a <- data.frame(color=c("red","orange","blue","white"),safe=c("N","N","Y","Y"))
# transpose and make it a dataframe.
new_a <- data.frame(t(a), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# makes the column names the first row of the new dataframe
names(new_a) <- new_a[1,]
# now you can get rid of the first row.
new_a <- new_a[-1,]
> new_a
     red orange blue white
safe   N      N    Y     Y
```

Comment: How in the world did I not come across this command in my googling? But how do I get the column names to come out instead of [,1] [,2] [,3] and [,4], or as V1, V2, V3, V4 in View(a)?

Comment: Cory, thanks, this demonstrates more features of R that I need to learn, and I'm going to have to think about the square bracket notation to fully internalize it. Thank you, I've marked your answer as the solution. 

As it turns out, I was going to post what I had found...

    `dcast(a,1~color,value.var="safe")`

The problem with that is that the first column is a throw away, and I can't figure out a way around it.

Comment: Yeah, this is a "base" R solution. A solution using plyr or some such package would look different.